# Java Web Accessing Resources from external Component

Tags: jsf, xhtml

I have An Applications consists of multi war and I want to share resources such as layout.xhtml pages,images,resources messages and persist.xml, a template for all these components (JSF pages)`.
I solved it using Custom Resolver within JSF(facelets.RESOURCE_RESOLVE)`

1. Is ResourceResolver necessary or not?

If there is another solution that is more efficient, please comment below.

Comment: where is the duplication??

Comment: At the top of the Q